# Modifying Executable python file issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python project that just need to modify a label.

This is the structure of the project.

[image]

If the user click on `GeneraXml.exe` the application will run, but I need to modify a lable.
I opened the `GeneraXml.spec` file in `NotePad++` and based on information, it seems that it reads the `main.py` file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None
added_files = [
         ( 'header.gif', '.' ),
         ( 'ko.gif', '.' ),
         ( 'ok.gif', '.' )
         ]

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[':\\Users\\UUUU\\Desktop\\New'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='GeneraXML',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

I opened the `main.py` file with `NotePad++` and changed the label... then I tried to recreate again exe file with this command line: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` 
But when I open the new exe file I see just a black window.

Could you please help me to understand what is the issue? how can I modify a lable of `.py` file and create executable file?

Comment: try to create a bat file (.bat) and add the GeneraXml.exe line and a last one with the command pause. Executing this batch it will run the GeneraXml.exe however now the prompt window wont close because of the pause. So you can see if some error happens...

Comment: I did it, but again it remains in the prompt window and will close and prompt ask me to insert a key but nothing is happen...

Comment: don't you get any error message when you create it again? Don't you get any error mesage when you run .exe in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? Do you have the same problem when you use pyinstaller without changing code in main.py? Maybe you changed too much and now it can't run.